# problem with javascript callback

Tags: jquery, ios, api, mobile, geolocation

So here is the code I have:

```
$.getJSON("http:\/\/tinygeocoder.com\/create-api.php?g=" + lat + "," + lng + "&callback=?", function(data) {
      alert(data);};
```

and it's working fine in chrome and safari... but fails in mobile safari.  Here is the error i'm getting:

```
http://tinygeocoder.com/create-api.php?g=39.67997936,-104.(removed for space)&callback=jsonp1302553994489
SyntaxError: Parse error
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is all this (strange (to me)) escaping (`\/\/`) necessary?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? To test, put this somewhere in your JS: `alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);`.

Comment: I get the same error with or without the escapes.

Comment: im using the google hosted 1.4.2

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: No it's not needed at all. the `/` character needs no escaping in a string.

Comment: @Guffa: As I thought, but felt it wasn't beyond the realms of possibility for jQuery to betray me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I try to browse to that URL, I get this response back:

```
Bummer, we've had too many queries and one of our data sources has decided not to work. Please <a href="mailto:info@tinygeocoder.com">let us know</a>.
```

As this is not JSON, it causes your parsing error.

Comment: just try again. They get overloaded sometimes and this error pops up.  I get that in chrome once in awhile.  were probably slamming them now that I put this up on stackoverflow...

Comment: +1 Beat me to it :) @jtmkrueger I also believe this is your problem - changing `$.getJSON()` to `$.get()` gets rid of the error in Mobile Safari since you're no longer insisting the response is JSON and forcing jQuery to parse it. It's unfortunate that tinygeocoder returns this error with 200 OK instead of an error condition.

Comment: I cried, then emailed them.  That's how I found out what the error meant.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding, can you show me what you changed the code to to get a response in mobile safari? If i just use .get() i get a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error...

Comment: @jtmkrueger Sorry, should've clarified - yes, you'll get that with your cross-domain request. I was using a local JSON file. Try it out - if you create an invalid JSON response and use `$.getJSON()` - Mobile Safari complains. However, if the same JSON response is fetched with `$.get()`, there won't be an error. I'm not suggesting you use `$.get` instead of `$.getJSON()` - I'm just trying to verify that the underlying problem is indeed that the response is NOT JSON when it is expected to be and that is causing the error.

Comment: OK! This actually turned out to be the right answer... still wrestling this though. need to figure out what the deal is...

Comment: jtmkrueger: Well, the deal is that the error message is not well designed as it's not returned as JSON. You simply have to request the data as plain text and check if it's JSON or not, and then use `jQuery.parseJSON` to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have some URL sensitive characters in your `lat` and `lng` variables.  You could try using `encodeURIComponent()` on those.

Comment: This didn't change anything eric.